# Windows Shared memory and different Compilers weird behavior

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, gcc, shared-memory

I had the two different process interacting with each other using the shared memory and i observe that it doesn't work as expected for some reason, the thing is, the buffer for some reason fills up with additional zero's when i put data into it. Here is what i do:

Process1 vc++ (msvc2012 active solution platform Win32):

```
LPTSTR pBuf =(LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMap,   // handle to map object
                        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
                        0,
                        0,
                        256);
if(!pBuf)
{
        //handle errors
}
WaitForSingleObject(hExchangeData,INFINITE); //here i'm waiting data from the second process it should be DWORD value

DWORD someValue=0;
CopyMemory((PVOID)&someValue,pMemBuf,sizeof(DWORD)); //i get it and everything is ok, then the second process waits for this process to put some data in
int pBufSize=sizeof(DWORD); //counter
CopyMemory((PVOID)(pBuf+pBufSize),&hHandle1,sizeof(HANDLE));
pBufSize+=sizeof(HANDLE);
CopyMemory((PVOID)(pBuf+pBufSize),&hHandle1,sizeof(HANDLE));
SetEvent(exDone);
```

Here is process two, written with MinGW: Thread model: win32, gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)

```
 pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMap,
               FILE_MAP_WRITE | FILE_MAP_READ,
               0,
               0,
               256);

   if (pBuf == NULL)
   {
       //handle errors
   }
   DWORD myVal = 228;
   memcpy(pBuf,&myVal,sizeof(DWORD)); //here i wrote some dword in there which first process is successfully receiving
   SetEvent(dwordWritten); 
   int mySize = sizeof(DWORD); // counter
   WaitForSingleObject(handlesWrittine,INFINITE); //waiting for some handles

   CopyMemory((PVOID)&myHandle1,(PVOID)(pBuf+mySize),sizeof(HANDLE));
   mySize += sizeof(HANDLE);
   CopyMemory((PVOID)&myHandle2,(PVOID)(pBuf+mySize),sizeof(HANDLE));
```

So basically int the first process(msvc) i wrote two handles with the length of 4 bytes, because `sizeof(HANDLE) =4` on both versions, i checked with `printf`, and i expect to receive 4 bytes as well in the second(mingw+gcc) process, but what happens is that the memory buffer structure in the first process looks like this

```
 1234 //dword
 0012  //handle1
 0013  //handle2
```

but in the second process:

```
  1234 //dword
  0000  
  0012  //handle1
  0000  
  0013  //handle3
```

So from the second process last `CopyMemory` instruction i get the 0012 handle value. Why is it different like this? Why do i get additional Zero's in the second process? I tried using the msvc platform for BOTH processes and it works fine, but with mingw, gcc no.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with alignment and padding of member variables.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious i need to align those three variables to zero alignment?

Comment: pBuf being declared as LPTSTR is the issue.  See my new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the actual problem this time.

pBuf is of type LPTSTR.  Which on UNICODE builds is a short* pointer.  On ANSI builds this is a char* pointer.  I suspect your Visual Studio project is defining UNICODE in the build environment and MinGW is not. Hence, this expression within the CopyMemory call in the first code sample :

```
(pBuf+mySize)
```

Evaluates to incrementing pBuf by mySize*2 bytes.

The simple fix is to declare pBuf as type LPSTR or as a char*.

```
char* pBuf = (char*) MapViewOfFile(hMap,   // handle to map object
                        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
                        0,
                        0,
                        256);
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! My inattention to the windows types made me a lot of wasted time.

Answer (score -1):

Several issues.

First, this line looks way off:

```
mySize += HANDLE;
```

Does that even compile?  Don't you intend to say `mySize += sizeof(HANDLE)`

In any case, are you absolutely sure `sizeof(HANDLE)` is 4 in MinGW?  I have my doubts.

HANDLE is typically defined as follows in `<winnt.h>`

```
typedef void *HANDLE;
```

So `sizeof(HANDLE)` will either be 4 or 8 depending if you are building as a 32-bit or a 64-bit build.

I suspect your Visual Studio configuration is in 32-bit mode, as that's the usual default. And your MinGW build is 64-bit.

You'll see the same differences if you configure your Visual Studio project to product a 64-bit build.

Comment: Sorry i was editing the post and messed up the code a bit, yes it is `mySize += sizeof(HANDLE)`, and i checked that is equal to 4, using `printf("sizeof(HANDLE)=%d\n",sizeof(HANDLE));` alsi i double checked it from the console gdb debugger with `print`.

Comment: Also in the task manager my process is displayed as `process.exe*32`